# Which formula can I use to prove following?

Tags: combinatorics

Given set $|A| = k$ and pairwise distinct sets $B_1, B_2, ... , B_p \subset A$, where $1 < p \le k\ $ 
and $\ \forall i\ |B_i| = k - p + 1$.

Then $\exists j \ \exists m :j \neq m \ |B_j \cap B_m| = k-p$.

Seems, that this is wrong iff $k = 6, p = 4$.

Is there any formula to solve it?

Comment: What does "unequal sets" mean?  Have you tried to test this statement on simple examples, e.g., $A = \{1, 2, 3, 4, 5\}$?

Comment: So, pairwise distinct sets?

Comment: @avs, edited. Yes, I have some examples, but the problem is general case for any $k$ and $p$.

Comment: Are the inequalities $1>p>k$ correct? Because this doesn't make much sense.

Comment: @Fimpellizieri, well, for $p = k$ it still holds. However, if $p = 1$ we cant take two different sets.

Comment: If $p>k$ then $k-p<0$. What does it mean for a set $S$ to satisfy $|S|<0$?

Comment: @Fimpellizieri, corrected them.